# CSS para o plugin Timthumb para o CakePHP

Tags: php, css, cakephp

Existe alguma forma de aplicar classes **CSS** a miniaturas criadas pelo plugin **Timthumb** para o **CakePHP**? O atributo `'class'` causa um erro.

**Código**

```
$this->Fancybox->setPreviewContent($this->Timthumb->image('/img/gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] , array('width' => '267px', 'height' => '189px')));
```

Comment: Só mais um par de detalhes: agora não aparece aqui no código a definição do atributo de classe que deu origem à pergunta & aqui no Stack é mais fácil ler o código indentado deste jeito: http://pastebin.com/rLr7Hvhd

Comment: O problema não era a classe em si, mas o facto de no plugin não existir esse atributo no helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolução**

Apenas me bastou aplicar nas `<td>` a `class="thumbnail"`, no entanto depois tive que adicionar, também, o `style="display:inline-block;"` pois as miniaturas passaram a ser apresentadas na vertical, e não 4 por cada `<tr>`, como eu queria.

**Código**

```
<h2>Galeria</h2>
<table >
<tr>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach( $gallery_images as $gallery_image ):?>
        <td align="center" class="thumbnail" style="display:inline-block;">
        <?php
            $src3 =$this->webroot. 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
            $this->Fancybox->setProperties( array( 
            'class' => 'fancybox3',
            'className' => 'fancybox.image',
            'title'=>'Single Image',
            'rel' => 'gallery1'
                  )
            );
            $this->Fancybox->setPreviewContent($this->Timthumb->image('/img/gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] , array('width' => '267px', 'height' => '189px')));
            $this->Fancybox->setMainContent($src3);
            echo $this->Fancybox->output();
    ?>
    </td>
    <?php $i++;
        if($i==4){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $i=0;   
        }
    ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tr>
```